# Azure Cosmos SQL results with WHERE clause doesn't make sense

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm running some queries against my Cosmos database, and the results don't seem to make sense. I am getting 0 results with some queries when I know I should be getting some results. Here are the results of the queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) from c where c.ownerTime='2010775021_202009'                        -- 165229
SELECT COUNT(c.id) from c where c.ownerTime='2010775021_202009' and c.source='five9'   -- 132100
SELECT COUNT(c.id) from c where c.ownerTime='2010775021_202009' and c.source<>'five9'  -- 0
SELECT COUNT(c.id) from c where c.ownerTime='2010775021_202009' and c.source=null      -- 0
```

My goal is to get a count of all items where the `source` attribute does not equal 'five9'. But that query (as seen above) returns a count of 0. As you can see, in the first query, the total number of items in this partition is 165,229. And from the second query, the total number of items in this partition where `source` is equal to 'five9' is 132,100. Common sense tells me that the number of items where the source is not equal to 'five9' should be 33,129. Why are my queries showing 0?

One thing to keep in mind is that when I go to inspect the items in raw form, the items that don't have `source='five9'` don't have a `source` attribute at all. Could that be causing this behavior? Also, `ownerTime` is the partition key.

Here is a small sample of data:

```
SELECT c.id,c.ownerTime,c.source from c where c.ownerTime='2010775021_202009'
...
{
    "id": "L2n8D4c4GOFQTUA",
    "ownerTime": "2010775021_202009"
},{
    "id": "3524zXL55zQmQ8qk",
    "ownerTime": "2010775021_202009",
    "source": "five9"
}
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) from c where c.ownerTime='2010775021_202009' and (not IS_DEFINED(c.source) or c.source<>'five9')
```

Comment: Well, that actually worked, But the query was literally 2000x more expensive. Surely there is a way to do with without a sub-select?

Comment: @MattSpinks I update my answer. You can try that SQL.

Comment: In such cases I always use the pattern `(c.source ?? null) != 'five9'`. RU-wise, I assume that's equivalent to Steve's answer.

Comment: @MoB. thanks for that insight. IN testing, it uses the same RU as the answer, and I like how short it is.